# XSL count problem

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the sample xml file:

```
<sample s="false">
  <assertionResult>
    <name>XML Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Error Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>Success Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>false</error>
  </assertionResult>
  <assertionResult>
    <name>XML Schema Assertion</name>
    <failure>false</failure>
    <error>true</error>
  </assertionResult>
</sample>
```

The original file consists of *sample* nodes such as the one above.
I need to count all *sample* nodes with the s="false" attribute, except those which have an *`<error>true</error>`* inside.
This is the code which I am using for counting:

```
select="count(/testResults/*[attribute::s='false'])"
```

The problem is that I don't know how to exclude nodes which have the  child with the "true" value.

Comment: what XSLT processor are you using?   Curious because I've only seen XPath syntax like @s='false' used until now.   attribute::s='false' surprised me.

Comment: @Nareen - '@' is a shorthand for the attribute axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list several sets of square brackets to add new clauses to your condition i.e.

/testResults/*[@s='false'][not(.//error = 'true')]

Comment: +1 correct answer. BTW `[conditionA][conditionB]` is equivalent to `[conditionA and conditionB]`... Some people find the latter more readable.

Comment: @LarsH: `$node-set[$bool1][$bool2]` is not quite the same as `[$bool1 and $bool2]` because in the former case `[$bool2]` will be evaluated for each instance of the already filtered node set `$node-set[$bool1]`, but in later case both expression `$bool1` and `$bool2` will be evaluated for each instance of the whole node set `$node-set`. That's why `$node-set[.='something' and position()=1]` is not the same as `$node-set[.='something'][1]`.

Comment: @Alej: good point that in the case of `position()` (explicit or implicit), the rule doesn't hold. I can never remember the details of the rules for `position()`.

Answer (score 0):

select="count(/testResults/*[attribute::s='false' **and not(error='false')**])"

Comment: This puts the test for the `error` element at the wrong level (and says 'false' instead of 'true'). Try `and not(.//error = 'true')`